# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this codes but when I try these code I am getting:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post' cannot be null
>   this error.

I could not find any solution. I tried another functions which are work they are worked but this one is not work.

```
?>
<form method="post">
Buraya yaz <br><textarea style="resize:none" name="post"></textarea> <br><input type="submit" value="Gönder">
</form>

<?php 
if(empty($_POST['post'])){
echo 'you should fill the area.';
exit;
}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
$users->sendpost($post);
}
?>

public function sendpost($post){
$query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (`post`) VALUES (?) ");
$query->bindValue(1, $post);
try{
$query->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}   
}
```

Comment: What is `$post`?  Where do you declare it?  Your value is currently in `$_POST['post']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert $post = $_POST['post'];

```
$post = $_POST['post'];

if(empty($_POST['post'])){
echo $errors[] = 'you should fill the area.';
}
if (empty($errors) === true){
$users->sendpost($post);
}
```

Comment: This one is finally works man! Thank you so much! Really really so much!

Comment: @user3006359: if this fixed it, then you need to turn on your notices and warnings - you need to be able to see an on-screen message if an undefined variable is encountered during development.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you're displaying the error but not doing anything about it. Change it to:

```
if(empty($_POST['post'])){
  echo 'you should fill the area.';
  exit;
  }
```

However, as the main recommendation, you should use exceptions that can be catched:

```
if(empty($_POST['post'])){
  throw new Exception("You should fill the area.");
  }
```

This is not the only error, as noted in the comments by @RocketHazmat . If you didn't understand what he's saying, you should do `$users->sendpost($_POST);` instead of `$users->sendpost($post);`.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem. The 'field name' in view page and the column name of database was different. My problem was:
     `"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'MoneyMethod' cannot be null"`. 
My form input tag:`{!! Form::select("MoneyMethod", $MoneymethodInfo, null,["class"=>"form-control MoneyMethod required","id"=>"MoneyMethod"]) !!}`, notice the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' and in my database table `$table->string('MoneyMethod', 100);` the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' is same as form but in my controller `$riskfund->Moneymethod  = Input::get('Moneymethod');` look carefully the spelling of 'Moneymethod' differs from view page and database table column. After correcting the spelling, it is working now.
So, please check the spelling of 'post' in form, controller, database table. it may help you.