# Getting the following error while posting data PDO, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting an error like this when I submit a form. I have no clue what exactly is wrong in what I am doing here.

Kindly have a look at my code below please:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'r_maritalstatus' ne peut être vide (null)

In English the message reads, "The column 'r_maritalstatus' may not be empty (null)."

If I select a value in `r_maritalstatus` then error shows for other field.

Here is this code:

```
if(!isset($error)){
        try {

        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO resumes (memberID, r_name,r_email,r_mobile,r_address,r_dob,r_maritalstatus,r_nationality,r_religion,r_sex,r_objective,r_languagesknown,r_hobbies,r_expcategory,r_exptype,r_exptitle1,r_expcompany1,r_expcity1,r_expfrom1,r_expto1,r_expdescription1,r_exptitle2,r_expcompany2,r_expcity2,r_expfrom2,r_expto2,r_expdescription2,r_exptitle3,r_expcompany3,r_expcity3,r_expfrom3,r_expto3,r_expdescription3,r_exptitle4,r_expcompany4,r_expcity4,r_expfrom4,r_expto4,r_expdescription4,r_exptitle5,r_expcompany5,r_expcity5,r_expfrom5,r_expto5,r_expdescription5,r_eduinstname1,r_edudegree1,r_edustudyfield1,r_educity1,r_edupassed1,r_eduinstname2,r_edudegree2,r_edustudyfield2,r_educity2,r_edupassed2,r_eduinstname3,r_edudegree3,r_edustudyfield3,r_educity3,r_edupassed3,r_eduinstname4,r_edudegree4,r_edustudyfield4,r_educity4,r_edupassed4,r_eduinstname5,r_edudegree5,r_edustudyfield5,r_educity5,r_edupassed5,r_skill1,r_skillexp1,r_skill2,r_skillexp2,r_skill3,r_skillexp3,r_skill4,r_skillexp4,r_skill5,r_skillexp5) VALUES (:memberID, :r_name, :r_email, :r_mobile, :r_address, :r_dob, :r_maritalstatus, :r_nationality, :r_religion, :r_sex, :r_objective, :r_languagesknown, :r_hobbies, :r_expcategory, :r_exptype, :r_exptitle1, :r_expcompany1, :r_expcity1, :r_expfrom1, :r_expto1, :r_expdescription1, :r_exptitle2, :r_expcompany2, :r_expcity2, :r_expfrom2, :r_expto2, :r_expdescription2, :r_exptitle3, :r_expcompany3, :r_expcity3, :r_expfrom3, :r_expto3, :r_expdescription3, :r_exptitle4, :r_expcompany4, :r_expcity4, :r_expfrom4, :r_expto4, :r_expdescription4, :r_exptitle5, :r_expcompany5, :r_expcity5, :r_expfrom5, :r_expto5, :r_expdescription5, :r_eduinstname1, :r_edudegree1, :r_edustudyfield1, :r_educity1, :r_edupassed1, :r_eduinstname2, :r_edudegree2, :r_edustudyfield2, :r_educity2, :r_edupassed2, :r_eduinstname3, :r_edudegree3, :r_edustudyfield3, :r_educity3, :r_edupassed3, :r_eduinstname4, :r_edudegree4, :r_edustudyfield4, :r_educity4, :r_edupassed4, :r_eduinstname5, :r_edudegree5, :r_edustudyfield5, :r_educity5, :r_edupassed5, :r_skill1, :r_skillexp1, :r_skill2, :r_skillexp2, :r_skill3, :r_skillexp3, :r_skill4, :r_skillexp4, :r_skill5, :r_skillexp5)');         
        $stmt->execute(array(
                     ':memberID' => $uid,
                     ':r_name' => $rname,
                     ':r_email' => $remail,
                     ':r_mobile' => $rmobile,
                     ':r_address' => $raddress,
                     ':r_dob' => $rdob, 
                     ':r_sex' => $rsex,
                     ':r_maritalstatus' => $rmaritalstatus,
                     ':r_nationality' => $rnationality,
                     ':r_religion' => $rreligion,
                     ':r_objective' => $robjective,
                     ':r_languagesknown' => $rlanguagesknown,
                     ':r_hobbies' => $rhobbies,
                     ':r_expcategory' => $rjobcategory,
                     ':r_exptype' => $rjobtype, 
                     ':r_exptitle1' => $rjobtitle1, 
                     ':r_expcompany1' => $rjobcompany1,
                     ':r_expcity1' => $rjobcity1, 
                     ':r_expfrom1' => $rjobfrom1, 
                     ':r_expto1' => $rjobto1, 
                     ':r_expdescription1' => $rjobdescription1,  
                     ':r_exptitle2' => $rjobtitle2, 
                     ':r_expcompany2' => $rjobcompany2, 
                     ':r_expcity2' => $rjobcity2, 
                     ':r_expfrom2' => $rjobfrom2, 
                     ':r_expto2' => $rjobto2, 
                     ':r_expdescription2' => $rjobdescription2,  
                     ':r_exptitle3' => $rjobtitle3, 
                     ':r_expcompany3' => $rjobcompany3, 
                     ':r_expcity3' => $rjobcity3, 
                     ':r_expfrom3' => $rjobfrom3, 
                     ':r_expto3' => $rjobto3, 
                     ':r_expdescription3' => $rjobdescription3,  
                     ':r_exptitle4' => $rjobtitle4, 
                     ':r_expcompany4' => $rjobcompany4, 
                     ':r_expcity4' => $rjobcity4, 
                     ':r_expfrom4' => $rjobfrom4, 
                     ':r_expto4' => $rjobto4, 
                     ':r_expdescription4' => $rjobdescription4,  
                     ':r_exptitle5' => $rjobtitle5, 
                     ':r_expcompany5' => $rjobcompany5, 
                     ':r_expcity5' => $rjobcity5, 
                     ':r_expfrom5' => $rjobfrom5, 
                     ':r_expto5' => $rjobto5, 
                     ':r_expdescription5' => $rjobdescription5,  
                     ':r_eduinstname1' => $reduinst1, 
                     ':r_edudegree1' => $redudegree1, 
                     ':r_edustudyfield1' => $redustudyfield1, 
                     ':r_educity1' => $reducity1, 
                     ':r_edupassed1' => $reduyear1,  
                     ':r_eduinstname2' => $reduinst2, 
                     ':r_edudegree2' => $redudegree2, 
                     ':r_edustudyfield2' => $redustudyfield2, 
                     ':r_educity2' => $reducity2, 
                     ':r_edupassed2' => $reduyear2,  
                     ':r_eduinstname3' => $reduinst3, 
                     ':r_edudegree3' => $redudegree3, 
                     ':r_edustudyfield3' => $redustudyfield3, 
                     ':r_educity3' => $reducity3, 
                     ':r_edupassed3' => $reduyear3,  
                     ':r_eduinstname4' => $reduinst4, 
                     ':r_edudegree4' => $redudegree4, 
                     ':r_edustudyfield4' => $redustudyfield4, 
                     ':r_educity4' => $reducity4, 
                     ':r_edupassed4' => $reduyear4,  
                     ':r_eduinstname5' => $reduinst5, 
                     ':r_edudegree5' => $redudegree5, 
                     ':r_edustudyfield5' => $redustudyfield5, 
                     ':r_educity5' => $reducity5, 
                     ':r_edupassed5' => $reduyear5,  
                     ':r_skill1' => $rskill1,
                     ':r_skillexp1' => $rskillexp1, 
                     ':r_skill2' => $rskill2,
                     ':r_skillexp2' => $rskillexp2, 
                     ':r_skill3' => $rskill3,
                     ':r_skillexp3' => $rskillexp3, 
                     ':r_skill4' => $rskill4,
                     ':r_skillexp4' => $rskillexp4, 
                     ':r_skill5' => $rskill5,
                     ':r_skillexp5' => $rskillexp5
         ));

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

echo print_r($_POST);
}
```

thanks and regards

Comment: so where does `$rmaritalstatus` get defined? did you confirm that your massive pile of placeholders and fields are actually aligned properly, and you didn't miss one somewhere?

Comment: My French is kinda rusty but I'm guessing you've got a `NOT NULL` constraint on a field into which you're attempting to insert a `NULL` value... comme çi : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058252/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-post-cannot-be-nu

Comment: im confused, is this related with placeholder in the form u mean?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: When dealing with large field sets you might want to consider using `INSERT table SET field = :value` syntax. Makes it easier to keep track of what data goes where

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: ^ *Spidey sense* on that one.

Comment: @CD001 *C'est exact.* - "cannot be empty / null". ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- dank u wel ;)

Comment: @CD001 you are right now its fixed. thanks alot mate

Answer (score 2):

In your database schema, you have `r_maritalstatus` column defined as `NOT NULL`. This means that whenever you do `INSERT`, you have to pass some value to this column, you can't just omit it or set to `NULL`.

**Solutions**

1. If you need to always have `r_maritalstatus` set to something, this means that `NOT NULL` constraint is correct, and it stops operation to warn you about this. Do a `var_dump($rmaritalstatus);` before `->execute`, it will most likely be `NULL`. So, the solution is to validate this variable before doing an INSERT, that you always receive the value here from the resume form.
2. If you don't care about `r_maritalstatus` always having a value, it means you need to remove the constraint. Just go to your database tool and change this field to `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`.
3. If you do this, but you have the same problems with many other fields and you're getting tired of changing them to `NULL`, it's most likely that this code was meant to work in the **non-strict MySQL mode**. In this mode, MySQL would ignore `NOT NULL` and set the omitted string field to empty and numeric field to 0. *It's recommended to do the following only if you're desperate to fix the application that suddenly got broken after moving to another server or updating MySQL to the newer version.* Change my.cnf file to have this line: `sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` (the least strict mode). Restart mysql server and try again. Additionally, if you want to change it only for your application, you can add these right after you connect to the database with `$db = new PDO(...)`:

   ```
   $db->exec('SET SESSION sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"');
   $db->exec('SET GLOBAL sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"');
   ```

**Symptoms:**

It often happens when developers create database schema when in non-strict mode and don't notice `NOT NULL` that is being set by the DB management tool they use by default (such as phpMyAdmin, for example). Then they move it to the server or upgrade to the newer version of MySQL and wonder, why they suddenly receive many errors like '1048 Integrity constant violation' or '1364 Field doesn't have a default value'. Usually it has to do with the changed mode.

Comment: This is a well-crafted and helpful answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!