# PHP if runs twice and generates duplicate records to the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am writing a little piece of code for the one game where users can bid and the biggest bid wins the round (like the auction). There is a 1-minute timer and when it ends, some actions occur. I will write all the details below.

Timer script:

```
$auctionTimer = 1;

$target_time = strtotime('+' . $auctionTimer .  'minutes', strtotime($r1['date']));
$current_time = time();
$seconds_left = $target_time - $current_time;
$minutes_left = floor($seconds_left / 60);

if (strlen($minutes_left) != 2) {
  $minutes_left = sprintf("%02d", $minutes_left);
}  

$seconds_left -= $minutes_left * 60;
$seconds_left = floor($seconds_left);

if (strlen($seconds_left) != 2) {
  $seconds_left = sprintf("%02d", $seconds_left);
}
```

Something is bad with the `if ($current_time > $target_time && $ragr1['count'] >= 1) {` check:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, user, bid, date FROM 
    tb_auction_bids ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt1_while = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, user, bid, date FROM 
    tb_auction_bids");
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id FROM tb_auction_winners ORDER BY 
    id DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt6 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tb_users SET money = money + :win WHERE id = 
    :user_id");
$stmt9 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_auction_winners (user_id, user, win) 
    VALUES (:user_id, :user, :win)");
$stmt11 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, user FROM tb_auction_bids ORDER 
    BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt12 = $pdo->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE tb_auction_bids");

$agr1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM tb_auction_bids");
$agr2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(bid) AS sum FROM tb_auction_bids");


$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1_while->execute();
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt11->execute();

$agr1->execute();
$agr2->execute();

$r1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$r3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$r11 = $stmt11->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ragr1 = $agr1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ragr2 = $agr2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($current_time > $target_time && $ragr1['count'] >= 1) {
  $stmt9->execute(array(
    ':user_id' => $r11['user_id'],
    ':user' => $r11['user'],
    ':win' => $ragr2['sum']
  ));
  $stmt6->execute(array(
    ':win' => $ragr2['sum'],
    ':user_id' => $r1['user_id']
  ));
  while ($r1 = $stmt1_while->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $stmt7->execute(array(
        ':user_id' => $r1['user_id'],
        ':aukciono_id' => $r3['id'],
        ':user' => $r1['user'],
        ':date' => $r1['date'],
        ':bid' => $r1['bid']
    ));
  }
  $stmt12->execute();
}
```

I guess I should not post PDO queries because the problem is not about SQL, it is about PHP. If you are not in this page (.../auction, e.g.), when the 1-minute timer ends, it does nothing at all. You have to go again to the .../auction, e.g., to get a reward. Should I use JavaScript to check if the timer ended and then execute the file?

This is how it looks like (video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CZcnd3RTNw

Also, I get

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post'
>   cannot be null" error and I looked into this thread:
>   [SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post' cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058252/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-post-cannot-be-null)

but it did not help. The `$r1['aukciono_id']` is defined also as another variables but only the `$r1['aukciono_id']` gives an error.

`if ($current_time > $target_time && $ragr1['count'] >= 1) {` should run only once but it runs twice and generates duplicate MySQL records. Maybe it is because of that PDO error? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: There is no `$stmt9` mentioned in your query.

Comment: neither `$stmt6`

Comment: Sorry, edited my question.

Comment: Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself :) Thank you for your ideas, the problem was with the while loop. I should use another query instead.

So, I added:

```
$stmt7 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_aukciono_istorija (user_id, 
    aukciono_id, user, date, bid) SELECT user_id, aukciono_id, user, date, bid 
    FROM tb_auction_bids");
```

And instead of:

```
while ($r1 = $stmt1_while->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $stmt7->execute(array(
        ':user_id' => $r1['user_id'],
        ':aukciono_id' => $r3['id'],
        ':user' => $r1['user'],
        ':date' => $r1['date'],
        ':bid' => $r1['bid']
    ));
}
```

Use this one:

```
$stmt7->execute();
```

Only one line of code. Cool :)